# Access web services https to http

Tags: java, angularjs, ssl

I have two application running on the same server for example  application A is running on https(SSL) another application B is running on http(Not SSL). My task is Application A have to access some webservices from applicaion B. While doing on local its running perfectly. But if i am running on server. Throwing error like SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.

Note: Application A is angularjs. Application B is springboot.

I am create one subdomain and deploy the application B.No luck.

Need some explanation why its not working on server. How is it working on server. My guess i have to apply https on my application B.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be a single web app with spring boot at the backend and Angular at the frontend. IMO SSL hosted app cannot call non-ssl url. The spring boot should also be in https.

Comment: But its not a single page app. Because angularjs application have separate backend thats running on php(laravel). angularjs app on ssl-url (https). If i want to access the springboot app non-ssl(http). I should enable https on springboot app. Is it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am configure ssl for my application B (springboot).Now application working fine.Thanks